# Shabbos, Yom Tov and Clothing

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, clothing, yom-tov

Is there any *halacha* brought down:

1. That one has to wear *begadim mechuvadim* on *Shabbos* or *Yom Tov*?
2. Does this apply for *davening*?

Comment: I don't understand question 2

Answer (score 2):

in shulchan aruch siman reish samach beis seif beis it says ישתדל שיהיו לו בגדים נאים לשבת... you should have nice clothing for shabbos its brought in other places how yom tov is the same as shabbos however for davening there is a whole other set of halachos of how you need to be dressed (namely that you have to be "presentable") that is brought in shulchan aruch siman tzadik aleph (see mishnah berurah and shulchan aruch harav for details)